# Bootstrap contactForm background opacity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a contact form I made in bootstrap. When I inspect elements I see that it takes CSS properties from the class .well

In this class, the background-color is set as :

```
background-color: #f5f5f5;
```

I modified it to :

```
background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
```

This works. Then I want to add opacity :

```
background-color: rgb(245,245,245,0.7);
```

The background becomes totally transparent.

But if I set up opacity to 0.7, then the whole contact form is semi-transparent.
How can I have only the contactForm bacground semi-transparent ?

Here is the contactForm html:

```css
#contactForm.well {
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245,0.7);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- Form itself -->
  <form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <legend>Formulaire de contact</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre nom" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez entrer votre nom" />
        <p class="help-block"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez entrer votre email" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Veuillez entrer votre message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Veuillez entrer votre message" minlength="5" data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" maxlength="999"
        style="resize:none"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="success"></div>
    <!-- For success/fail messages -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Envoyer</button>
    <br />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's a typo. You need to change _rgb_ into _rgba_, so change it into `background-color: rgba(245,245,245,0.7);`

Comment: Lol! You are right! It works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rgba() when including alpha value, try using

```
background-color: rgba(245,245,245, 0.7);
```

Comment: Good catch, fixed it